# How to prevent Maven from dowloading content into default user Repository folder?

Tags: maven, configuration

I recently installed Maven and I want to avoid it from downloading content into the Windows OS hard drive. I added the following line in the global `settings.xml` file:

```
<localRepository>D:\path\to\maven\local\repository</localRepository>
```

And as soon as I run `mvn clear` on a sample project it creates content into the `%USERPROFILE%\.m2\repository` folder.

How to configure Maven for storing content at `D:\path\to\maven\local\repository` only?

Comment: What do you mean by "prevent downloading content" into "default user repository? This is by design the location to cache artifacts which will be used during the build which will prevent to download by each build....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using eclipse to build your project then eclipse comes with its own embedded Maven. Default location for the maven repository would be `~/.m2/repository`. You can change the Default maven installation to your maven installation from `Preferences --> Maven --> Installations`  and then add location of your maven installation.